# How do I make a C# project that 3 users can work on at the same time?

Tags: c#, xna

Me and two others are starting to make games, we all have some knoledge of C# and VB.Net, we are using C# with the XNA Managed Runtime Environment to make a game.. We have one problem we can't find an answer too though. How do all three of us work on the same project? I saw something about Team Foundation Server, but would that allow us all to work on the project? Or is that just for statistics and time activated builds..

Thanks, Matthew

Comment: Look no further than https://github.com/

Comment: have you considered something like [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) plus [Source Tree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview)?

Comment: Yes, TFS does allow you to all work on the project at the same time.  there are other types of source control too, such as Subversion, which is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need source control. That could be Team Foundation server, it integrates nicely with Visual Studio. Git is also a very popular alternative, but it's more complex.

I started out with SVN server and that was simple and easy for me. You should google for what suits your needs.

Source control is something that runs separately from your project, it has little or nothing to do with your preference of language.

Answer (score 0):

Any [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) solution will work to help you manage the project in a team.  This includes Team Foundation Server, but also [github.com](https://github.com/), Bitbucket and other options.

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server is primarily used as a source control tool (can also be used for build management, storing test cases etc.). If you want to maintain a history of the changes to any code, then go ahead with Team Foundation Server or some other source control. A source control would also help you in making local changes and then merging your change with the changes made by others afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes TFS (Team Foundation Server) will help you.

1. It has a source control, which keeps track of changes made by individual developer and let you merge your changes with code on server or rollback any changes
2. It provides project management capability, to create user stories and tasks then assign each commit with task to let everyone know that "this change is performed for following task"

and many more ..